# Read only certain characters from inputstream (C++)

Tags: c++, istream

I have a class `BitSet` with a data member `d_bits`. `d_bits` is an object that has member functions `readString` and `resize`. Now I want to define the extraction operator (`operator<<`) for `BitSet`, which ignores leading whitespaces and then reads zeroes and ones from the istream and stops once a different character is encountered. I made the following cumbersome function:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &in, BitSet &bitSet){
  while (in.peek() == ' ')
    in.ignore();

  string bits;
  char ch;
  while (in.peek() == '1' || in.peek() == '0'){
    in.get(ch);
    bits.append(1, ch);
  }
  bitSet.d_bits.resize(bits.length());
  bitSet.d_bits.readString(bits);
  return in;
}
```

It works correctly, but I am unhappy with it for several reasons. Ignoring whitespace characters one by one seems unnecessarily tedious. Also, once the whitespaces are ignored, reading the characters one by one and then appending them to a string also seems excessively slow. I looked around for the member functions of istreams that might be convenient but I could not find a better way of doing this. So is this the preferred way of extracting only a part of the contents of an istream?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws

Comment: Short answer: no there isn't. Define "excessively slow". Input streams use `std::streambuf` to internally buffer input in larger blocks. Just the fact that you have to code input stream processing one character at a time doesn't mean that's how you'll actually be reading the input file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By excessively slow I mean that it feels like there should be a faster way to this, but I guess the details of istream prevent this.

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that the implementation of `double d; std::cin >> d;` extracts one digit of the number at a time, until the entire number gets collected, then converts the extracted characters into a `double`. That's how things work (the actual implementation might be doing the conversion in parallel to parsing the input a character at a time). Just like you implemented your `>>` operator so it can be used to do the entire job, in one shot, but in reality everything happens one character at a time, underneath the covers.

Comment: Depending on your situation on the input stream, there are other whitespace character that you probably want to ignore as well.  In particular, '\t', '\r', and '\n' (but perhaps others).

Comment: @Eljay Ow yeah, thanks I missed that. Thanks for the comment Sam, I did in fact know this but I was thinking the C++ folks likely did a good job in their implementation so why try to reinvent the wheel :)